# Setting up a local DNS server to the public

Tags: apache, dns

So, I am able to host a web server on my local computer to the public, by simply running Apache httpd on my computer on port 80, which is behind a residential NAT, so I port forward TCP 80 to my local computer. Now I want to have a domain name, so I register a subdomain on "freedns.afraid.org", more specifically I set up an "A record" for (e.g.) "foo.mooo.com" to "100.100.100.100".

Now, anybody with access to the Internet can access my local computer's httpd by typing in "http://foo.mooo.com" into their browser. Now, I want my server to be able to handle URL's such as: "http://sub.foo.mooo.com", which at this point will always fail to resolve.

The domain registration site "freedns.afraid.org" does not allow "wildcards", but this is kind of irrelevant anyways because I want to know how to set up a DNS server on my own. So I download and install a DNS server "MaraDNS" (seems more simpler than "BIND") as an authoritative-only nameserver.

I first set it up to run locally, and after changing my Internet connection settings to use "127.0.0.1" as my DNS server, I am successfully able to assign arbitrary hostnames to arbitrary IP addresses by creating "A records" within "MaraDNS".

So "MaraDNS" itself seems to be working fine. I then learn about "NS records", and how they are able to delegate certain domains on one nameserver to another nameserver. So I first port forward UDP 53 and made sure it is accessible to the Internet (tested with nmap), and I go to "freedns.afraid.org" and delete my previous "A record" and try to create an "NS record" for "foo.mooo.com" to "100.100.100.100".

But "NS records" apparently do not support IP addresses, they can only forward to other domain names. So I try to create an "NS record" for "foo.mooo.com" to "foo-ns.mooo.com", and an "A record" for "foo-ns.mooo.com" to "100.100.100.100".

Now "foo.mooo.com" fails to resolve, "foo-ns.mooo.com" works fine. Can somebody give some tips?

Answer (score 1):

MaraDNS was not setup properly, and I simply needed these DNS settings:

wthini freedns.afraid.org:

foo.mooo.com. 3600 IN NS foo3.mooo.com.
foo3.mooo.com. 3600 IN A 100.100.100.100

within MaraDNS:

*.foo.mooo.com.       100.100.100.100 ~